# Using VLOOKUP in an array formula on Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

Effectively I want to give numeric scores to alphabetic grades and sum them. In Excel, putting the `LOOKUP` function into an array formula works:

```
{=SUM(LOOKUP(grades, scoringarray))}
```

With the `VLOOKUP` function this does not work (only gets the score for the first grade). Google Spreadsheets does not appear to have the `LOOKUP` function and `VLOOKUP` fails in the same way using:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(grades, scoresarray, 2, 0)))
```

or

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(VLOOKUP(grades, scoresarray, 2, 0)))
```

Is it possible to do this (but I have the syntax wrong)? Can you suggest a method that allows having the calculation in one simple cell like this rather than hiding the lookups somewhere else and summing them afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't see the formulae in your example (just values), but that is exactly what I'm trying to do in terms of the result; obviously I can already do it "by the side" and sum separately - the key for me is doing it in one cell.

I have looked at it again this morning - using the `MATCH` function for the lookup works in an array formula. But then the `INDEX` function does not. I have also tried using it with `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` without success. Finally, the `CHOOSE` function does not seem to accept a cell range as its list to choose from - the range degrades to a single value (the first cell in the range). It should also be noted that the `CHOOSE` function only accepts 30 values to choose from (according to the documentation). All very annoying. However, I do now have a working solution in one cell: using the `CHOOSE` function and explicitly listing the result cells one by one in the arguments like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(CHOOSE(MATCH(D1:D8,Lookups!$A$1:$A$3,0),
                                     Lookups!$B$1,Lookups!$B$2,Lookups!$B$3)))
```

Obviously this doesn't extend very well but hopefully the lookup tables are by nature quite fixed. For larger lookup tables it's a pain to type all the cells individually and some people may exceed the limit of 30 cells.

I would certainly welcome a more elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I think the answer is no. From the help text on
http://docs.google.com/support/spreadsheets/bin/answer.py?answer=71291&query=arrayformula&topic=&type=

> The real power of ARRAYFORMULA comes when you take the result from one of those computations and wrap it inside a formula that does take array or range arguments: SUM, MAX, MIN, CONCATENATE,

As vlookup takes a single cell to lookup (in the first argument) I don't think you can get it to work, without using a separate range of lookups.

Answer (score 1):

> Google Spreadsheets does not appear to have the LOOKUP function

Presumably not then but it does have now:

[image: SO27774 example]

`grades` Sheet1!A2:A4
`scoringarray` Sheet1!A2:B4

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old, but I'd been struggling with this same problem for some time.  I finally came across a solution (well, Frankenstiened one together).  It's only slightly more elegant, but should be able to work with large data sets without trouble.

The solution uses the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(), MATCH())))
```

as a surrogate for the vlookup function.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

you can do so easily like this by hardcoding it in VR table:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {{"A", 6};
                                         {"B", 5};
                                         {"C", 4};
                                         {"D", 3};
                                         {"E", 2};
                                         {"F", 1}}, 2, 0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

or you can use some side cells with rules:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, E2:F, 2, 0)), ))
```

[image: 6]

---

**<sub>alternatives: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123741/186471</sub>**